# clear gridview data from javascript or jquery

Tags: gridview, datasource

Thanks for advance

i have a dropdown and a grid and file upload . after file upload the uploaded data listed on grid ,
while changing the dropdown i need to clear the gridview 
i have done this code but its not working ,

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_File').remove();
```

its clears the grid but after that if we add data to grid blank rows added. how to clear the data source. i only want to list uploaded lists

```
    foreach (GridViewRow gv in grd_File.Rows)
    {
        //GridViewRow row = grd_File.Rows[j];
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        TextBox filename = (TextBox)gv.FindControl("txtfilename");
        TextBox sort = (TextBox)gv.FindControl("txtsort");
        TextBox file= (TextBox)gv.FindControl("txtfile");

        dr["FileName"] = filename.Text.ToString();
        dr["sort"] = sort.Text.ToString();
        dr["file"] = file.Text.ToString();           
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    if (hdnfilename.Value != "")
    {
        dr["FileName"] = hdnfilename.Value.ToString();
        dr["sort"] = Convert.ToInt32(grd_File.Rows.Count) + Convert.ToInt32(1);
        dr["file"] = filenm;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);


    // }
    grd_File.DataSource = dt;
    grd_File.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added update panel to the dropdown and using register script i have called javascript function`

```
protected void cmbFileType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grd_File.DataSource = null;

    //rebind to gridview
    grd_File.DataBind();

    //hdnimages.Value = "";
    ////hdnfilename.Value = "";
    //hdnfile.Value = "";
    //hdncount.Value = "0";
    System.Text.StringBuilder csbld2 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    csbld2.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    csbld2.Append("filetypechange()");
    csbld2.Append("</script>");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "AutoPostBackScript", csbld2.ToString(), false);
}
```